# Wordpress Gutenberg RichText no color selection

Tags: wordpress, colors, jsx, richtext, gutenberg-blocks

I was trying to add Color selection for text in RichText component, but it's not working.

`<RichText  allowedFormats={['core/bold', 'core/text-color']} tagName="h5" value={props.attributes.title} onChange={handleTitleChange} />`

I tried `core/color` also, no luck... Bold option appears, but no color, no special dropdown menu for it - nothing... If I don't use `allowedFormats` it shows me all the formats, but still no Color.

I'm here to see if it's any other option to do this without `<InspectorControls>`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this with the **block.json** file. You need to add color support in the block.json file to do this without using InspectorControls.

```
"supports": {
        "html":false,
        "color": {
            "background": true,
            "text": true,
            "gradients": true
        }
    },
```

You need to add **useBlockProps()** to your RichText component for color support to edit and save files.

**edit.js**

```
import { useBlockProps,RichText } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
         <RichText
                {...useBlockProps()}
                onChange={handleTitleChange}
                value={props.attributes.title}
                placeholder={__("Your text")}
                tagName="h5"
                allowedFormats={["core/bold"]}
        />
```

**save.js**

```
import { useBlockProps, RichText } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
            <RichText.Content
                {...useBlockProps.save()}
                tagName="h5"
                value={props.attributes.title}
            />
```

Now you can set the text-color and background color of the RichText component.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I mean, I need to change text color in RichText component. This code you gave added Color support for block on the right side, but it have no effect with the RichText component text color.

Comment: @RytisPlečkauskas, Have you add useBlockProps in your RichText component?

Comment: Just added, still the same.

Comment: @RytisPlečkauskas, Please check my updated answer. It is working for me.

Comment: Worked, I forgot to initialize it

Comment: But what about if I have more then one RichText, for example after Title I have Description, and it changes the color of both of them